# Yii uploading images in Yiistrap for carausel

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

In my web application I  need to upload images from my system and use it in Yiistrap carausel. I copied the image into my images directory  and gave the address .But its not recognizing , its not showing the image although I gave the correct  adress of my image
My code for using the image in Yiistrap widgets.

```
<?php echo TbHtml::carousel(array(
    array('image' => '/var/www/store3/images/download.jpg/830x477', 'label' => 'First Thumbnail label', 'caption' => 'image1'),
    array('image' => '/var/www/store3/images/download1.jpg/830x477', 'label' => 'Second Thumbnail label', 'caption' => 'image2'),

)); ?>
```

I also tried all combinations by removing the full path naming ,adding the relative path , but nothing seems to work .

The error I am getting is..

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Any body kindly help me with this .I am stuck up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It worked at my end. Using Yii's baseurl is the best way to reference directories.

```
<?php echo TbHtml::carousel(array(
array('image' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/download.jpg', 'label' => 'First Thumbnail label', 'caption' => 'image1'),
array('image' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/download1.jpg', 'label' => 'Second Thumbnail label', 'caption' => 'image2'),
)); ?>
```